# Jquery unable to return to active state on animated menu list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu list that animates the background position on mouseover and this is working. When backgroundPosition: 0 the menu item is active.  But I want the first item in the list to return to being active when the user is not hovering over the other list items.

This is what I have so far, The movesover animated effect is working but Im not sure how to get the first item to return to being active state.

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    //Edited...
    //services menu background effect 
    var timer;
    function invocation() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('#services li:first a').stop().animate({
                backgroundPosition: 0
            }, 500);
        }, 300);
    }
    $('li.menu a').each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            backgroundPosition: -416
        });
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                backgroundPosition: 0
            }, 500)
            if ($(this).attr('id') != 's_active') {
                $('#services li:first a').stop().animate({
                    backgroundPosition: -416
                }, 500);
            }
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }).mouseout(function() {
            hover = false;
            $(this).stop().animate({
                backgroundPosition: -416
            }, 500)
            invocation();
        });
    });
    $('#services li:first a').css({
        backgroundPosition: 0
    }, 500);
    //invocation();
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="services">
    <h1>Services</h1>
    <ul>
        <li id="s_active" class="menu"><a href="#">Semi / Intensive courses</a> </li>
        <li class="menu"><a href="#">Pass plus / Motorway tuition</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a href="#">Block bookings</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a href="#">Mock theory and Mock practical tests</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: could you give us working jsfiddle to work on it :)

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/wDwg6/   but the background image is not visibly animating because I cant add a back ground image to the a tags.

Comment: It seems that your .mouseout() and .mouseleave() is fighting over who gets to animate the bg position.

Comment: I finally got it to work as above but surely there is a more efficent way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'll do it [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/killerbytes/H8cdY/)

just replace the

```
 doBackgroundEffect()
```

with your backgroundPosition animation